# Web App password protection UNIX style

Tags: mysql, password-protection

More a conceptual question and actually not a problem, but I'm rather curious on comments to the concept:

On modern Unix systems, you have a shadow passwd, storing all the passwords of all users. The file is only readable with certain privileges and not by "normal" users, thus preventing even the encrypted passwords of being disclosed.

For a web application, all concepts I have seen are storing User-ID and password in just one table like

`|uid|name|surname|address|....|passwdhash|...|`

Following the idea above, I've done this:

```
Table users
  |uid|name|surname|address|....|....|...|

Table passwords
  |rowid|keyhash|passwdhash|... other| critical| stuff| ....
```

There is no SQL relation between both tables (aka foreign key constraint or so.) Tables are completely disjoint!

So, finding the password for a user follows this algorithm:

```
SELECT ... from users

compile keyhash from user data

log in to DB as privileged user
   SELECT passwdhash from passwords where keyhash = <compiled value>
logoff from DB
```

obvious that table passwdhash has select/read/update only granted to a particular user.

Advantages so far:

Even if someone MIGHT get access to the DB through the application, its still very hard to get to users passwords (and even other relevant information). Brute force or rainbow of course is not covered by this, it will only prevent stealing entire database lists with user id and password hashes. And even if someone cracks in to the app, he is still not able to read out the password table like on the Unix systems above

Q:

1. has anyone ever heard of a concept like this?
2. has anyone ever implemented such thing and
3. what are the experiences in a runtime environment

Thanks for not putting it off topic after 3 microseconds ... ;-)

Comment: If you're going to do this, it may be easier to just put the authentication on a different server entirely, using something like OAuth.

Comment: fair enough, although not really "easy". Second thought: you will have the same problem on the second server with uid's and passwords as well. Problem moved, but not solved?

Comment: The purpose is privilege separation, right? I suggested OAuth because you get even more privilege separation, and it's easier since other people have already written servers to do OAuth. If you mean the thing about not connecting the two tables, I think you're wasting your time. The real improvement in this is that only one DB user has access to the passwords.